# MongoDB Aggregation $size on Nested Field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to perform a tricky aggregation to return the size of a nested array within a document in the collection.

Here is how to re-create my sample data:

```
db.test.insert({
    projects: [
        {
            _id: 1,
            comments: [
                'a',
                'b',
                'c'
            ]
        },
        {
            _id: 2,
            comments: [
                'a',
                'b'
            ]
        },
        {
            _id: 3,
            comments: []
        }
    ]
})
```

The aggregation I would perform goes here:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    // enter aggregation here
])
```

Here is the desired output:

```
[{
    projects: [
        {
            _id: 1,
            comment_count: 3
        },
        {
            _id: 2,
            comment_count: 2
        },
        {
            _id: 3,
            comment_count: 0
        }
    ]
}]
```

I'm struggling with how to write this. If I try the following:

`"projects.comment_count": {"$size": }`

The result returns the size of the resulting array:

```
[{
    projects: [
        {
            _id: 1,
            comment_count: 3
        },
        {
            _id: 2,
            comment_count: 3
        },
        {
            _id: 3,
            comment_count: 3
        }
    ]
}]
```

If I try to use the $map method like this:

```
"projects.comment_count": { 
    "$map": { 
        "input": "$projects", 
        "as": "project", 
        "in": {
            "$size": "$$project.comments"
        } 
    } 
}
```

It will return an array that looks like this for each object in the array:

```
[{
    projects: [
        {
            _id: 1,
            comment_count: [3, 2, 0]
        },
        {
            _id: 2,
            comment_count: [3, 2, 0]
        },
        {
            _id: 3,
            comment_count: [3, 2, 0]
        }
    ]
}]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't be much help to your question here, but wanted to say this is a well-worded question for a first-timer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea using `$unwind`, `$group` and then `$push` with `$size`. Finally `$project` to get rid of that `_id`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$projects"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      "projects": {
        $push: {
          _id: "$projects._id",
          comment_count: {
            $size: "$projects.comments"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

You can [see the result here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0_mJDWjYB9j)

Comment: Just one typo in the code, he wants the "id" with an hyphen, so the code inside the $push command should be _id:"$projects._id".

Comment: I ended up using most of this code. Because I have a much longer aggregation pipeline that pulls documents from multiple other collections upstream, I had to ditch that last `$project` and built my final output inside of the `$group` with reference to the top-level document using `$$ROOT`. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify each field inside the `in` argument of  [**`$map`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) aggregation and finally use [**`$size`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) with the `comments` array.

Something like this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "projects": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$projects",
        "in": {
          "_id": "$$this._id",
          "comment_count": {
            "$size": "$$this.comments"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "projects": [
      {
        "_id": 1,
        "comment_count": 3
      },
      {
        "_id": 2,
        "comment_count": 2
      },
      {
        "_id": 3,
        "comment_count": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```